# “Especially because” in German

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, idiomaticity

I often want to express a sentiment like:

> It was so nice to be outside this summer, especially because the winter was so cold!

Literally translated, *especially because* would be *insbesondere weil …* I’m not sure if this is just wrong, or if it sounds like German obviously translated from English. What would be a better to express this idea in more natural German?

Comment: Diesen Sommer war es so schön draußen zu sein, gerade wegen des kalten Winders.

Comment: Es war draußen so schön diesen Sommer, besonders da der Winter so kalt war.

Comment: Funny, I always get the feeling I’m using a Germanism when I write _especially because_.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- besonders weil
- insbesondere weil
- gerade weil
- vor allem weil

sind alles mögliche Alternativen, die im Deutschen gang und gäbe sind.

Comment: Das klingt nicht seltsam?: "Es war diesen Sommer so schön draußen zu sein, insbesondere weil der Winter so kalt war."

Comment: Oder 'insbesondere da der Winter...' oder wie Wrztprmft schreibt, 'gerade nach ...'.

Comment: @Phil Braun you can further shorten your sentence in german we would say it like: "Es war diesen Sommer so schön draußen, besonders weil es im Winter so kalt war".

Comment: *insbesondere* klingt schon ein wenig gestelzt wenn man vom Wetter spricht.

Answer (score 17):

A somewhat more free translation would involve not using a subclause:

> […], gerade nach dem kalten Winter.
>
> […], insbesondere angesichts des kalten Winters. [rather formal]
>
> […], erst recht nach dem kalten Winter. [rather colloquial]

In my opinion, these variants are more idiomatic.

Answer (score 6):

As others already pointed out, your translation is perfectly fine. However, one suggestion has not yet been made. IMHO, one of the best ways (stylistically) to translate your example sentence would be by using *zumal:*

> Es war (so) schön …, *zumal* der Winter sehr kalt war.

Yet, using *zumal* should perhaps not be your first choice in a colloquial conversation. It may be considered to be a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: *zumal* ist in bestimmten Wendungen absolut gebräuchlich, klar nicht in allen, in dieser aber schon.

Answer (score 3):

You could switch the order of the sentence:

> Gerade aufgrund des Winters Kälte war es schön, im Sommer draußen zu sein.

Comment: Almost sounds like poetry.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Besser wäre hier wohl *Nach des Winters Kälte*

Comment: What about *`Gerade nach dem kalten Winter war es schön, im Sommer draußen zu sein.`* which is much simpler (to understand)?

Answer (score -1):

"Vor allem weil..." fits perfect in this case. It's not formal. It is rather the usual phrase to emphasize something. "Insbesondere" is too formal to be used in everyday language.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please expand your answer in a way that it adds something to [User Unknown’s answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/25899/2594)?

Comment: This is either a comment to [user unknown’s answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/25899) who already noted these expressions or a duplicate of his answer. As such, it should be deleted/converted.

Comment: Just go ahead... Knock yourself out.